# Ruby 1.9.1 with rspec "can't modify frozen object"

Tags: ruby, rspec

I just updated to Ruby 1.9.1 and nearly all my rspec are broken giving me a "can't modify frozen object". Even the Rspec sample code from a generate rspec_controller fails.

```
RuntimeError in 'DownloadsController should use DownloadsController'
can't modify frozen object                                                                                                                                                          
/usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/timeout.rb:44:in `timeout'


Generated by the following code: 

it "should use DownloadsController" do
  controller.should be_an_instance_of(DownloadsController)
end
```

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace you can post?

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't get any trace except what's above... Even with --trace

Answer (score 6):

Are you use you aren't trying to stub something that is nil.

In 1.8 nil wasn't frozen.  It is however frozen in ruby 1.9.

Comment: Thhanks for the input. I'll try it perhaps this weekend. I've been sent on a contract and taken off my Rails project.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening `/usr/local/lib/ruby19/1.9.1/timeout.rb` and replace line 44 with the following:

```
begin
  return yield(sec) if sec == nil or sec.zero?
rescue => e
  puts e.backtrace.join("\n")
  raise e
end
```

Though this seems odd, in some cases I've found that this gives me more detailed information on the actual source of the problem. If you still don't know how to fix the problem, paste your results here and maybe it will help us track down the issue.